# Variance of importance sampling estimator

Tags: probability

I consider a target distribution $\mu$, a proposal distribution $\nu \gg \mu$ (both probability distributions),
$w= d\mu/d\nu$, $f$ a bounded function.

The question is : prove that 
$$
Var_{\nu} (fw) = \mu(f)^2 \nu\left[\left(
\frac{|f|w}{\mu(|f|)}-1
\right)^2\right]
$$
I keep messing with the definitions.